# Android MapView, finding center of map, determining end of animation from fling gesture

Tags: android

The closest thing I could find related to this was the following:

[android maps: how to determine map center after a drag has been completed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1773717/android-maps-how-to-determine-map-center-after-a-drag-has-been-completed)

I want to determine the final "resting place" of the center of the map after the user has "flung" it.  I am intercepting the touch event, when the user is lifting their finger up, but this doesn't work when the map is flung with a swipe motion, as the map continues to move at that point.  Is there a callback that can be implemented when the map animation is complete?  I looked at the documentation for the MapView, Overlay, MapController etc classes and I haven't seen anything that seems to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also have been looking for a "did end drag" solution that detects the map center at the moment exactly after the map ended moving. I haven't found it, so I've made this simple implementation that did work fine:

```
private class MyMapView extends MapView {

    private GeoPoint lastMapCenter;
    private boolean isTouchEnded;
    private boolean isFirstComputeScroll;

    public MyMapView(Context context, String apiKey) {
        super(context, apiKey);
        this.lastMapCenter = new GeoPoint(0, 0);
        this.isTouchEnded = false;
        this.isFirstComputeScroll = true;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
            this.isTouchEnded = false;
        else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
            this.isTouchEnded = true;
        else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE)
            this.isFirstComputeScroll = true;
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }
    @Override
    public void computeScroll() {
        super.computeScroll();
        if (this.isTouchEnded &&
            this.lastMapCenter.equals(this.getMapCenter()) &&
            this.isFirstComputeScroll) {
            // here you use this.getMapCenter() (e.g. call onEndDrag method)
            this.isFirstComputeScroll = false;
        }
        else
            this.lastMapCenter = this.getMapCenter();
    }
}
```

That's it, I hope it helps! o/

Comment: how do you use it with layout.xml? i keep getting this error http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3682139/custom-mapview-throwing-nosuchmethodexception-but-its-there